# How can I remove space between children in the row?

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HanIT.jpg)

I would like to remove space between icon and text. How can I remove space between children in the row?/////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
Widget topSection() {
  return Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
    children: [
      Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, top: 180),
          child: MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            color: Colors.black,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.done,
              size: 24,
            ),
            shape: CircleBorder(),
          )),
      Expanded(
          child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 180),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 4),
              child: Text("Wellness Coaching",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontFamily: "LatoR",
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w900)),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 4),
              child: Text("Connect to your data",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontFamily: "LatoR")),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: hello, please provide screen shot of your current and expected output!

Comment: Hello! Welcome to SO! I would advise you to share some more information on the kinds of results you are trying to achieve. Perhaps post an image of your app in its current state and how you actaully want it to to look. Also, please have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask so that the community can assist you better.

Answer (score 0):

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
```

Try deleting this line.